# BLE(Bluetooth low energy) Keyboard required any change for iOS16 onward?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, keyboard, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

Bluetooth keyboard (BLE HID) is working fine with iOS15, but for iOS16 the key event not working properly, working randomly or with some delay.

Any change required for HID hardware, or any changes required for iPhone settings (iOS16 onwards) ?